# Green image when encoding a video frame to PNG

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm wrote the following code to convert a decoded video frame to a PNG image. The code doesn't crash but the image data stored in 'avpkt' results in an all green image. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

```
// pFrame - the decoded frame
// avpkt - the packet to fill with the converted image
void convert_image(AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx, AVFrame *pFrame, AVPacket *avpkt, int *got_packet_ptr) {
    AVCodecContext *codecCtx;
    AVCodec *codec;

    *got_packet_ptr = 0;

    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(TARGET_IMAGE_CODEC);
    if (!codec) {
        printf("avcodec_find_decoder() failed to find decoder\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    codecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!codecCtx) {
        printf("avcodec_alloc_context3 failed\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    codecCtx->bit_rate = pCodecCtx->bit_rate;
    codecCtx->width = pCodecCtx->width;
    codecCtx->height = pCodecCtx->height;
    codecCtx->pix_fmt = TARGET_IMAGE_FORMAT;
    codecCtx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    codecCtx->time_base.num = pCodecCtx->time_base.num;
    codecCtx->time_base.den = pCodecCtx->time_base.den;

    if (!codec || avcodec_open2(codecCtx, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        printf("avcodec_open2() failed\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    int src_width = pCodecCtx->width;
    int src_height = pCodecCtx->height;
    enum PixelFormat src_pixfmt = pCodecCtx->pix_fmt;
    int dst_width = pCodecCtx->width;
    int dst_height = pCodecCtx->height;

    struct SwsContext *scalerCtx;

    scalerCtx = sws_getContext(src_width,
            src_height,
            src_pixfmt,
            dst_width,
            dst_height,
            TARGET_IMAGE_FORMAT,
            SWS_BILINEAR, //SWS_BICUBIC
            NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (!scalerCtx) {
        printf("sws_getContext() failed\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    AVFrame *pSrcFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();

    if (!pSrcFrame) {
        goto fail;
    }

    AVFrame *pFrameRGB = avcodec_alloc_frame();

    if (!pFrameRGB) {
        goto fail;
    }

    if (avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) pSrcFrame,
            pFrame->data,
            src_pixfmt,
            src_width,
            src_height) < 0) {

        printf("avpicture_fill() failed\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    int numBytes = avpicture_get_size(TARGET_IMAGE_FORMAT, src_width, src_height);
    uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(numBytes * sizeof(uint8_t));

    if (avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) pFrameRGB,
            buffer,
            TARGET_IMAGE_FORMAT,
            src_width,
            src_height) < 0) {
        printf("avpicture_fill() failed\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    sws_scale(scalerCtx,
              (const uint8_t * const *) pSrcFrame->data, 
              pSrcFrame->linesize,
              0,
              src_height, 
              pFrameRGB->data, 
              pFrameRGB->linesize);

    int ret = avcodec_encode_video2(codecCtx, avpkt, pFrameRGB, got_packet_ptr);

    if (ret < 0) {
        *got_packet_ptr = 0;
    }

    fail:
    if (codecCtx) {
        avcodec_close(codecCtx);
    }

    if (scalerCtx) {
        sws_freeContext(scalerCtx);
    }

    if (ret < 0 || !*got_packet_ptr) {
        av_free_packet(avpkt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code reads the first frame and saves it to PNG.

```
    #define CHECK_ERR(ERR) {if ((ERR)<0) return -1; }

    int convert_first_frame_to_png(std::string const & inputVideoFileName, std::string const & outputPngName)
    {
        av_register_all();
        avcodec_register_all();

        ::AVFormatContext * ctx = NULL;
        int err = avformat_open_input(&ctx, inputVideoFileName.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
        CHECK_ERR(err);
        err = av_find_stream_info(ctx);
        CHECK_ERR(err);

        AVCodec * codec = NULL;
        int strm = av_find_best_stream(ctx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, &codec, 0);

        AVCodecContext * codecCtx = ctx->streams[strm]->codec;
        err = avcodec_open2(codecCtx, codec, NULL);
        CHECK_ERR(err);

        SwsContext * swCtx = sws_getContext(codecCtx->width, 
            codecCtx->height, 
            codecCtx->pix_fmt, 
            codecCtx->width, 
            codecCtx->height, 
            PIX_FMT_RGB24, 
            SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, 0, 0, 0);

        for (;;)
        {
            AVPacket pkt;
            err = av_read_frame(ctx, &pkt);
            CHECK_ERR(err);

            if (pkt.stream_index == strm)
            {
                int got = 0;
                AVFrame * frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
                err = avcodec_decode_video2(codecCtx, frame, &got, &pkt);
                CHECK_ERR(err);

                if (got)
                {
                    AVFrame * rgbFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
                    avpicture_alloc((AVPicture *)rgbFrame, PIX_FMT_RGB24, codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height);
                    sws_scale(swCtx, frame->data, frame->linesize, 0, frame->height, rgbFrame->data, rgbFrame->linesize);

                    AVCodec *outCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_PNG);
                    AVCodecContext *outCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
                    if (!codecCtx) 
                        return -1;                  

                    outCodecCtx->width = codecCtx->width;
                    outCodecCtx->height = codecCtx->height;
                    outCodecCtx->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_RGB24;
                    outCodecCtx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
                    outCodecCtx->time_base.num = codecCtx->time_base.num;
                    outCodecCtx->time_base.den = codecCtx->time_base.den;

                    if (!outCodec || avcodec_open2(outCodecCtx, outCodec, NULL) < 0) {
                        return -1;
                    }

                    AVPacket outPacket;
                    av_init_packet(&outPacket);
                    outPacket.size = 0;
                    outPacket.data = NULL;
                    int gotFrame = 0;
                    int ret = avcodec_encode_video2(outCodecCtx, &outPacket, rgbFrame, &gotFrame);
                    if (ret >= 0 && gotFrame)
                    {
                        FILE * outPng = fopen(outputPngName.c_str(), "wb");
                        fwrite(outPacket.data, outPacket.size, 1, outPng);
                        fclose(outPng);
                    }

                    avcodec_close(outCodecCtx);
                    av_free(outCodecCtx);

                    break;
                }
                avcodec_free_frame(&frame);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked, I still need to find out what my issue is but this will be helpful.

Comment: Try to use `av_picture_copy` instead of `avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) pSrcFrame, pFrame->data...`

Comment: got error:time="2019-02-27T17:00:42+07:00" level=info msg="ffmpeg: [png @ 0xd800000] AVFrame.format is not set\n"
time="2019-02-27T17:00:42+07:00" level=info msg="ffmpeg: [png @ 0xd800000] AVFrame.width or height is not set\n"